# Creating a local copy on each task, still not providing closure?

Tags: c#, multithreading, for-loop, closures, task

**Background**

Currently I am writing a program where two threads run concurrently, each accessing the critical region and writing a message to the console. The program involves two tasks, which I'm denoting *1* and *2* based on an integer defined as a local variable for each. Here is the code snippet where the tasks are created and run:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task[] tasks = new Task[2];
    Mutex m;

    // create the named mutex
    m = new Mutex(false, "mutex_name");

    // create two tasks that will each access the same critical region
    for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
    {
        tasks[i] = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            int iCopy = i;
            int iterations = 20;

            // run code that continuously enters the critical region
            for (int j = 0; j < iterations; j++)
            {
                WriteConsole(m, iCopy);
            }
        });
    }

    // wait for all of the tasks to finish
    foreach (var task in tasks)
    {
        task.Wait();
    }

    // wait for the user to exit the program
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Okay, so notice that I've specifically followed the practice of creating the local copy of the the iteration variable on each task. I've done this, and in past cases it has provided closure. This time, I end up with both tasks containing the value *2* which indicates that even though I've made copies, the variables are still referencing the original for-loop. Why?

Additionally, here is the code for the `WriteConsole` function:

```
static void WriteConsole(Mutex m, int name)
{
    // enter the critical region
    m.WaitOne();

    // acknowledge that we've entered the critical region
    Console.WriteLine("Task: " + name + " has entered the critical region.");

    // hold the mutex for a little while
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    // acknowledge that we've left the critical region
    Console.WriteLine("Task: " + name + " will now leave the critical region.");

    // leave the critical region
    m.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

Here is the program output for the above, I've truncated this a bit since there is so much because obviously we are in a loop. In any case, the loop runs through to conclusion with every line printing *Task: 2*:

> Task: 2 has entered the critical region.
>
> Task: 2 will now leave the critical region.
>
> Task: 2 has entered the critical region.
>
> Task: 2 will now leave the critical region.
>
> Task: 2 has entered the critical region.

**"What I've Tried"**

I've tried unrolling the for loop to see if there was something else the matter, or if this is truly an issue with loop/variable closure. When I unroll the loop my output looks much better:

> Task: 0 has entered the critical region.
>
> Task: 0 will now leave the critical region.
>
> Task: 1 has entered the critical region.
>
> Task: 1 will now leave the critical region.
>
> Task: 0 has entered the critical region.
>
> Task: 0 will now leave the critical region.
>
> Task: 1 has entered the critical region.
>
> Task: 1 will now leave the critical region.
>
> Task: 0 has entered the critical region.
>
> Task: 0 will now leave the critical region.
>
> Task: 0 has entered the critical region.
>
> Task: 0 will now leave the critical region.
>
> Task: 1 has entered the critical region.
>
> Task: 1 will now leave the critical region.

Most probably know what I mean when I say that I've *unrolled* the for-loop, but I will assume nothing and include the code snippet for that anyway:

```
tasks[0] = Task.Run(() =>
{
    int iterations = 20;

    // run code that continuously enters the critical region
    for (int j = 0; j < iterations; j++)
    {
        WriteConsole(m, 0);
    }
});
tasks[1] = Task.Run(() =>
{
    int iterations = 20;

    // run code that continuously enters the critical region
    for (int j = 0; j < iterations; j++)
    {
        WriteConsole(m, 1);
    }
});
```

It looks as if it is truly a closure issue at this point, based on the above test. Now, the final thing I'd like to add is that whether/not the loop is rolled/unrolled, both tasks are executing. I've been able to set breakpoints and see that either task is executing as it should during the debug session.

**Question**

What's really getting me is that the "create a local copy" method does not seem to be providing the closure.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you made `iCopy` inside the task, which starts only when `Task.Run` finishes its preparations and gets to executing your code. In other words, there is a race between the loop modifying `i` and your code invoked by `Task.Run` capturing `i`'s value in `iCopy`, and the `for` loop wins the race.

Moving the declaration outside the task fixes the problem:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++) {
    int iCopy = i;
    tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => {
        int iterations = 20;
        // run code that continuously enters the critical region
        for (int j = 0; j < iterations; j++) {
            WriteConsole(m, iCopy);
        }
    });
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/nvU4iR)

Comment: Thank you, just a side note. Why does that demo application you used, have task 0 enter the critical region to completion... and follows with task 1 entering the critical region to completion? Just the luck of the draw?

Comment: This scares me about some things I've done in the past... Is there a condition where say... the task's preparation happens to win the race?

Comment: @Snoop I changed the waiting time to `100` so that ideone wouldn't bounce the task on a 5-second timeout that they have on the site.

Comment: @Snoop Between the moment the thread starts and the assignment `iCopy = i` happens there is enough preparation time to let your `for` loop to complete its run. You can check the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs) to see what `Task.Run` does. The code starts at line 5614.